# Elliptical Coordinates PDE, wave equation and separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, partial-derivative

I need some help with this problem.  I know how to use the method of separation of variables and that the constant lambda should give you trig functions with solutions at some interval of pi, which should be solutions of T(t).  It may be the elliptical coordinates that are throwing me off, but beyond there and some other scattered things I am not really sure what/where to start and am having trouble finding a resolution for this one.  If somebody can walk me through this it would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Problem]

Comment: What have you done so far?  Did you compute the derivative(s)?

Comment: I have computed:  
x partial: [2sinh^-1[sqrt{ci - 1} / sqrt{2}] ] * cos(n) 
y partial: sinh^-1(ci)sin(n) 

Really sorry about the horrible formatting not too sure how to do maxJax on comments.  I should have specified the second part of the question is where I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: But also since there are no initial conditions, when it says "compute the derivative of u w.r.t. ci in terms of x and y derivatives" isn't getting the partials for x and y the farthest we can go for part 1?

Comment: Initial values usually apply when we start with a differential equation.  Here we have started with a regular pair of functions and gotten their derivatives; note the instructions say not to solve the differential equation created in part $2$, so we wouldn't bother with initial values anyway.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  From that I gather that the 2 partials of x and y are sufficient for part 1. For part 2, we would separate out E, H, and T and it wouldn't actually matter that we do not have an expression for u, since we wouldn't use it anyway?  Also, my partials from pt 1 are incorrect, they should have been acos(n)sinh(ci) and asin(n)cosh(ci) for x and y.

Comment: Looking at this again, it seems that part 1 doesn't really seem to coordinate so much with part 2?